# Аналог функции peekb

Tags: c++, функции

Проблема следующая: имеется компилятор Dev-C++. В нем в библиотеке dos.h нет функции `peekb`.
Вопрос: где взять компилятор, который откомпилит мне екзэшник с этой функцией, либо любой аналог этой функции.

Comment: Если нужен gcc, то www.delorie.com/djgpp (правда у меня эта ссылка не открывается). Если нет -- то Borland, watcom (теперь, кажется, openwatcom), ещё кто-нибудь. Но неужели тяга к древностям настолько велика, что стоит искать компилятор c++ для dos? (Учтите, что многие из этих компиляторов были созданы ещё до выпуска первой редакции стандарта C++, так что язык там достаточно древний)

А вообще -- лучше бы эти окаменевшие экскременты мамонта забыть.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что программа, вызывающая peekb будет на современном оборудовании правильно работать. Все равно придется смотреть-разбирать исходник, чтобы убедиться в этом.

Вообще peekb читает байт по адресу, заданном в формате segment:offset, что характерно для архитектуры 8086.

Comment: А что, современные x86 процессоры уже разучились изображать 8086?

Comment: Можно и так сказать. По крайней мере их об этом специально просить надо.

Подробнее [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_8086) и [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC).

Comment: А двадцать лет назад я ещё видел винды в реальном режиме (windows 3.0). Дистрибутив -- шесть дискет...

Comment: @gecube Комментарии к ответу @gecube для меня кончились, поэтому -- здесь. Да и хрен с ней, с NTVDM, www.freedos.org, и можно полной грудью дышать пылью *dos.

Comment: @gecube, а не кажется, что не нам решать что человеку надо и как ему лучше? Начал бы кто мне вкручивать такое вместо простого ответа на простой вопрос - быстро бы отправился в известном направлении. Раз спрашиваю, значит надо...

Comment: @klopp, здесь другой случай. Судя по дискуссии автор вообще плохо разбирается в IT.

Comment: А где дискуссия? Я понимаю, что такие "функции" пишутся с закрытыми глазами, если хоть немного в теме. Но от автора вообще ни одного комментария :-)

Comment: @klopp, сейчас автор пытается спросить где взять микроскоп. А, оказывается, он хотел всего лишь им забить гвоздь (:-o !?). Вот я и пытаюсь предложить молоток, который почти наверняка есть в кладовке :-)

Comment: @klopp, об этом и речь (автор не отзывается, это о многом говорит).

С другой стороны, может он уже сам все сделал, а наши рассуждения по поводу peekb и истории ему неинтересны.

Comment: лабу по работе с bios нужно выполнить, даны примеры где используется эта функция, вот, гуглил плохо, не нашел ничего подобного

Answer (score 2):

Я хотел бы для себя уяснить - зачем автору вопроса эта функция? Глобальная задача какова? Просто практически 100%, что можно адаптировать код программы под нормальную современную операционную систему и обойтись без этого анахронизма, вызова `peekb()`.

Comment: @gecube, это проблема кучи вопросов. Цель автор не объясняет, как хочешь, так и придумывай.

Comment: Да какая разница зачем? Её "написать" - полторы секунды, быстрее, чем это выяснять :-)

Comment: И ещё секунда -- выяснить, что собранная программа не работает.

Comment: Далеко не факт. peekb(0xB800,0), например, отработает без проблем, а это чуть ли не самый распространённый случай. Но если и перестанет - и что? Ну, появятся правильные вопросы :)

Comment: Без проблем? Ню-ню. А что там в виндовой программе находится по адресу 0xB800?

Comment: А почему в виндовой? Очевидно, что peek и poke - DOS.

Comment: @alexlz, выяснить через секунду, что не работает - **это счастье**. А представьте эту ошибку в редко выполняемой ветке?

Comment: @avp любой может придумать массу неработающих конструкций, но это же не провод проверять их неработоспособность экспериментально.

Comment: @klopp так вот и подходим к более правильной формулировке вопроса: как сделать исполняемый файл для dos (вопрос "а на хрена это нужно?" остаётся за скобками).

Comment: Наверняка просто есть какие-то старые исходники, которые хочется собрать и посмотреть что получается :)

Comment: А потом окажется, что эта программа под ДОС обращается к памяти, которую NTVDM отказывается нормально эмулировать... и приплыли. И нужен полноценный DOS (хотя бы через виртуалбокс)

Comment: @gecube, зачем сразу VirtualBox, есть же DosBox еще, он может многое, чего не может NTVDM.

Comment: лабу по работе с bios нужно выполнить, даны примеры где используется эта функция, вот, гуглил плохо, не нашел ничего подобного

Answer (score 1):

Если это не критично, можно создать пустую аналогичную функцию. Компилятор скомпилирует, как будет работать не знаю. Второй вариант, найти в интернете исходники или написать эту функцию самому.

Comment: Да что там искать, обычное взятие байта по адресу :) Фактически тот же MK_FP для реального режима.

Comment: лабу по работе с bios нужно выполнить, даны примеры где используется эта функция, вот, гуглил плохо, не нашел ничего подобного

Comment: Т.е. dos однозначно. Возьмите dos'овский компилятор и работайте, а в душе пожелайте всего самого лучшего питекантропам, у которых Вы учитесь.

Насчёт компиляторов. Про Борланд писать не буду -- не интересовался, gcc -- http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/, то, что раньше называлось watcom -- http://www.openwatcom.org/

Comment: @capfsb Приношу извинения за ссылку на djgpp -- это компилятор для 32-битного режима (а если там нет 16бит, то без dos extendera функции биос будут недоступны)

Comment: Благодарю за совет, буду думать дальше

Comment: О чём думать-то :) peekb это даже не функция, а простейший макрос:

    #define peekb(_segment_,_offset_) *(unsigned char far *)MK_FP((_segment_),(_offset_))

Comment: @klopp И как это будет выглядеть при работе под "игровым" экстендером dos4gw? (Надеюсь, он ещё жив...)

Comment: Опять 25... Кто-то упоминал про dos4gw? Ну а если дойдёт до этого, то для этих таргетов MK_FP расширяется до линейного адреса, а не до segment:offset. До каких именно адресов нужно дотянуться у ТС я понятия не имею, и не моего ума это дело. Но видеопамять и BIOS под экстендерами адресуется без проблем. Даже куда большие диапазоны, для примера можно запустить drweb386.exe :-)

Comment: Да при чём тут dos4gw вообще? Такая задача ставилась? Вроде нет :)

Comment: Еще раз, dow4gw тут абсолютно ни при чём. Просто иллюстрация совета, что в данном случае нужен старенький 16-битный компилятор под dos.